# Error when using Baseclass.Contrib.SpecFlow.Selenium--> The "GenerateFeatureFileCodeBehindTask" task failed unexpectedly

Tags: c#, selenium, nunit, bdd, specflow

I am new to Specflow +selenium can someone help with this please:

When i add the "baseclass.contrib.specflow.selenium.nunit" to NuGet packages and build my solution ,its throwing me eroor :"The "GenerateFeatureFileCodeBehindTask" task failed unexpectedly"

[image]

and when I uninstall that package and build solution, it works fine.
what is the problem here?

The packages I have added to my solution are:

1. Specflow-3.3.57
2. Specflow.MsTest-3.3.57
3. SpecFlow.Tools.MsBuild.Generation-3.3.57
4. Selenium.WebDriver-3.141.0
5. baseclass.contrib.specflow.selenium.nunit-1.3.1

This is my App.congif file when i add the Baseclass.contrib package
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Baseclass.Contrib.SpecFlow.Selenium.NUnit package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Baseclass.Contrib.SpecFlow.Selenium.NUnit/1.3.2-tn40support2) says it is compatible with the latest SpecFlow versions, but it is not. It is not working since SpecFlow 2.0. This is an error in the NuGet package.

I assume you want to use this package to create scenarios for different browsers. If this is the case, have a look at our [Selenium example](https://github.com/SpecFlowOSS/SpecFlow.Plus.Examples/tree/master/SeleniumWebTest) with the SpecFlow+ Runner.

The example shows how to use SpecFlow and SpecFlow+Runner to run Selenium Web Tests for different Browsers.

---

Full disclosure: I am one of the maintainers of SpecFlow and SpecFlow+

Comment: Thanks. It took me a while to figure it out.
I will try with Specflow+Runner.